# If A is a model of (B is a model of C), then can we say that A is a model of C?

Tags: model-theory

The model relationship "$\models$" is first order definable, so one could have a sentence S which said that a structure B is a model of a sentence C, and S could in its turn be satisfied by a model A. Would A also satisfy C?

Comment: No. $A$ could be a model of the theory of numbers, and in $A$ you could describe that certain finite set is a model of the theory of the field with exactly $8$ elements. Certainly, $A$ is not a model of this theory.

Comment: No, since their languages needn't even coincide. For example, what if $A$ is a model of ZFC, and $B$ is an $A$-model of PA? Then letting $\varphi$ denote a sentence in the language of PA, certainly $B \models_A \varphi$ is well-formed, and so too is $A \models (B \models_A \varphi).$ But, surely $A \models \varphi$ is not.

Comment: What are $A,B,C$ exactly? The relationship is definable where? I think it only makes sense for (models of) arithmetic an set theory (or stronger). In any case, why would you think that?

Comment: @tomasz (thanks!) asked three questions. (1) why I should think that? Given the very good replies of Andres Caicedo and  user18921 , I no longer entertain the possibility; the original conjecture was based on examples such as a measurable cardinal also being an inaccessible cardinal, etc. I originally defined A,B,and C in very general terms, although the answers showed that I would have to put very strict conditions on all three in order for my question to (a) make sense, and (b) be true. As for where it's defined, I was thinking of Tarski's definition of satisfaction.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, many thanks. Excellent example.

Comment: @user18921, many thanks. Good point.